# Why do Record types oblige you to define its members types?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, record

It seems Record types oblige you to declare its members types:

```
type Point = { X:int; Y:int }
```

What is (or may be) the rationale behind it?

It seems that in F# you can (almost) always get away without having to define types when coding. This makes me think that maybe there is a strong theoretical foundation for this restriction. Is that the case?

### Response to Robert:

I do understand your point of concern, but it seems to me faulty reasoning. Let's see an example:

Let's assume F# lets us define typeless members:

```
type Point = { X; Y; }
```

Your reasoning goes around the fact that would this be the case, and one could find things as what follows in our code:

```
let a = { X=1; y=2 } //(1)
let b = { X="1"; y="2" } //(2)
```

Being that the case, the compiler wouldn't have a choice but to define (implicitly) `Point` as

```
type Point = { X:object; Y:object }
```

Now, you are probably not only creating Records but also using them. With that said, there would be probably some place in your code where you'd try to treat Point's members as integers:

```
let z = a.X + 2 //ERROR. goes against what is seen in (2)
```

and others where you'd be treating them as strings:

```
let w = A.X + "abc" //ERROR. goes against what is seen in (1)
```

Both would flag errors, so even if one would try to use mutually incompatible types for records' members, you couldn't! Would they be in some way compatible, and F# would find us the less generic possible root type to use.

The sensible point here is that in contrast to what you describe

> Would you ever want a field to suddenly change its type when moving
>   from one record to the next?

the Record types wouldn't *change* when moving from one record to the other. What could, in the worse case, happen, is that the Record's member types would be pretty generic (worse case, from the Object type).

But that is exactly the same risk you take when you write a method that only takes typeless arguments! And that, as we know, is allowed in F#.

So, unless I am missing something here, that is probably not the reason you *have* to define types in Records.

Comment: I think the short answer to your update comes down to "structural comparison," something that Thomas Petricek alludes to in some of his materials.  Your scenario presumes that the compiler infers the type of every "Point" *record* by the first instance of that record, something I'm quite sure the F# compiler does not do.

Comment: I've indeed heard about "structural comparison" in one of his posts here on SO, I believe. But I'll have to read about it as I know nothing of it.

Comment: Quite simply, what Thomas points out is that records are like Classes in c#, and tuples are like Anonymous Types.  It is reasonable in classes to specify a type for each member, or to have that type inferred statically *at the type level* (not at the instance level, which would be a runtime binding).

Comment: Unfortunately he doesn't say in the material I read exactly why they made the decision to require typing in records.  I can imagine that it makes things much easier for the compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If F# allowed you to define type-less records, then it would more likely interpret them as records with generic types of fields (as opposed to using `object` as you did in your edit). So assume that:

```
type Point = { X; Y }
```

Actually means:

```
type Point<'T1, 'T2> = { X : 'T1; Y : 'T2 }
```

Now you could write `{ X = 1; Y = 2 }` as well as `{ X = "foo"; Y = new System.Random() }`. However, this is just making records *less useful*. Records are supposed to document the meaning of the value in two ways 1) by labelling fields and 2) by specifying types of fields. Using the feature you suggest, you'd remove (2).

Of course, if you have a generic record, you can still define it as such explicitly (and use it with different values), but doing that automatically wouldn't probably be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some confusion here. F# is a statically typed language. F# compiler wont generate any code where it is not able to determine a type.

> But that is exactly the same risk you take when you write a method
>   that only takes typeless arguments! And that, as we know, is allowed
>   in F#.

There is no function which has type less parameters. Each parameter of a function has a type, whether a normal type like int, float or a generic type. If you dont provide types for a parameter it doesn't mean that is parameter less, the compiler will infer the type based on how the parameters are used and if in some case it is not able to infer the type it will throw compiler error.

Comment: When I refer to typeless parameters, I mean that you don't have to type them. I know the compiler will determine what is the most generic type they may have. If you read the whole OP you'll see that.